# how download file by url in jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

i have a website to download excel file. and now i need to send parameters to download file with this site url by jsoup. when i get bodystream(), i get a error,i do not know why and how can i  solute this matter.

```
Connection con = Jsoup.connect(url);
File downloadFile = File.createTempFile("TMP", ".xlsx");
con=con.timeout(300000);
con = con.header("Connection", "keep-alive")
         .header("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
con=con.data(parameters);
con=con.cookies(cookie);
Connection.Response res = con.ignoreContentType(true).method(POST).execute();
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(res.bodyStream(), downloadFile);
```

but i got `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request has already been read`
※sometimes i download download successfully with same code and parameters.
can you tell me how to solute this matter and download file by this way?

Comment: If you just want to download a file from the Internet, then consider using [HTTP client](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-http-client) which is part of the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me (with some changes to specify a URL; but you can include your other changes such as setting the cookies and to POST).

This just uses the inbuilt Java helper utility to read the input stream and save it to a file.

Given the error message you mentioned, I wonder if the FileUtils method you're using (what dependency is that from?) is sometimes re-reading the file.

```java
String url = "https://jsoup.org/rez/html5-logo.svg";
File downloadFile = File.createTempFile("TMP", ".svg");

Connection con = Jsoup.connect(url)
    .timeout(300000)
    .header("Cache-Control", "max-age=0")
    .ignoreContentType(true);
Connection.Response res = con.execute();
BufferedInputStream body = res.bodyStream();
Files.copy(body, downloadFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

System.out.println("Saved URL to " + downloadFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Alternatively, if you still get the same error, you could try reading the whole body into a byte array before saving:

```java
Connection.Response res = con.execute();
byte[] bytes = res.bodyAsBytes();
Files.write(downloadFile.toPath(), bytes);
```

Comment: i add cookies and tried reading the whole body into a byte array , but it does not work for this error.